# face recognition project showing error when running the command python app.py

Tags: python, flask, face-recognition

I have setup all the requirements in Face recognition project master . Everything gone good in last I run the command python app.py
this showing error

```
 Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "app.py", line 21, in <module>
    DATABASE_USER = os.environ['root']
  File "C:\Users\Satya Jeet\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\os.py", line 669, in __getitem__
    raise KeyError(key) from None
KeyError: 'root'
```

my app.py file some codes upto line 25

```
# * ---------- IMPORTS --------- *
from flask import Flask, request, jsonify
from flask_cors import CORS, cross_origin
import os
import psycopg2
import cv2
import numpy as np
import re


# Get the relativ path to this file (we will use it later)
FILE_PATH = os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__))

# * ---------- Create App --------- *
app = Flask(__name__)
CORS(app, support_credentials=True)



# * ---------- DATABASE CONFIG --------- *
DATABASE_USER = os.environ['root']
DATABASE_PASSWORD = os.environ['root']
DATABASE_HOST = os.environ['localhost']
DATABASE_PORT = os.environ['']
DATABASE_NAME = os.environ['detect']
```

Comment: Are you sure that you have variable 'root' in your system environment? Check content of os.environ dictionary.

Comment: Sorry but I am using first time. how to check the os.environ

Comment: for key in os.environ.keys():
    print(key, os.environ[key])

Comment: Sorry but where to write this code . I wrote this code print(key, os.environ[key]) in python and there is error showing
 File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'key' is not defined

Comment: Just create new text file. Change it's extension to *.py and use the code:
`import os`
`for key in os.environ.keys():`
    `print(key, os.environ[key])` If there is no database configs - something is done wrong.